# is this map an homotopic equivalence of pairs from (disk, sphere) to the disk seen attached to a space?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

Hello I was studying https://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/people/staff/vincent/cohomology.pdf

On page 18 given a space $A$ and a map $f:\mathbb{S}^{n-1} \rightarrow A$ he defines the cone $X := A \cup_f D^n$

I was trying to show that 
$(D^n, \mathbb{S}^{n-1}) \overset{\pi  i}{\hookrightarrow} (X,A)$ induces isomorphism on the homology (theorem 2.27). This problem has been taking me days and I haven't been able to do it in a way that preserves the commutativity of the diagram (all of my tries involves retractions that alter the inclusions)

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
H_n(D^n,\mathbb{S}^{n-1}) @>i_*> \cong>  H_n(X,A) \\
@V \cong VV @VV \delta V \\
H_{n-1}(\mathbb{S}^{n-1}) @>> f_*> H_n(A)\\
\end{CD}
$$

my idea was, as a first step, prove that

$(D^n,\mathbb{S}^{n-1}) \overset{( \pi , f)}\rightarrow ( \ \overline{D^n}, \overline{\{x \in D^n : |x| \geq 1/2 \}} \ )$

is an homotopic equivalence of pairs, where the bars mean projected inside $X$.

To do this, first prove an homotopic equivalence of pairs

$(D^n,\mathbb{S}^{n-1}) \overset{i}\rightarrow ( \ {D^n}, {\{x \in D^n : |x| \geq 1/2 \}} \ )$

and then compose with the projection $(D^n,{\{x \in D^n : |x| \leq 1/2 \}}) \overset{(\pi, f)}\rightarrow ( \ \overline{D^n}, \overline{\{x \in D^n : |x| \geq 1/2 \}} \ )$

to get the desired homotopic equivalence of pairs.

Is this route correct?

Comment: I assume you meant $f:\Bbb S^{n-1}\to A$, not $\Bbb S^n-1$, so I fixed it.

Comment: Yes I did! Thanks. By the way do you think that $(D^n,\mathbb{S}^{n-1}) \overset{( \pi , f)}\rightarrow ( \ \overline{D^n}, \overline{\{x \in D^n : |x| \geq 1/2 \}} \ )$
 is an homotopy equivalence of pairs? I honestly think is not because $D^n$ and $ \overline{D^n}$ can be non homotopic and very different, same with $\overline{\{x \in D^n : |x| \geq 1/2 \}}$ and $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$

the function $f$ might not be injective and might make serious identifications on $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$.

Comment: That leaves me really clueless on hy $(D^n, \mathbb{S}^{n-1}) \overset{\pi , f}{\hookrightarrow} (X,A)$ induces isomorphisms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is NOT an homotopic equivalence of pairs, rather it just induces an isomorphism in the homology.

The issue why I wasn't able to do this is that I didn't know much about homotopy of pairs. We need the following lemma:

Let $f:(X,A) \rightarrow (Y,B)$ a morphism of pairs. Then if  $f:X \rightarrow Y$ and $\left.f\right|_A:A \rightarrow B$ are both homotopic equivalences, then $f:(X,A) \rightarrow (Y,B)$ induces **isomorphisms** in the homology. Though is not necessarily an homotopic equivalence.

Given that, name $L= \{x \in D^n : |x| \geq 1/2 \}$

First, clearly $\mathbb{S}^{n-1} \hookrightarrow L $ induces a strong deformation rectract (I wasn't able to explicitely write it out) $r:L \hookrightarrow \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ $(\left.r\right|_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} = \mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}})$.

Thus $(D^n, \mathbb{S}^{n-1}) \hookrightarrow (D^n, L)$ induces isomorphism on the homology.

I think I can extend $r$ to $A \mathbin{\overset{d}\cup} L$ by setting $\left.r\right|_A= \mathbb{1}_{A}$. Then since $\left.r\right|_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} = \mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}$ r induces a map $\overline{r}:\overline{L} \rightarrow \overline{{S}^{n-1}}$ (I checked that is well defined on the quotient) that is a SDR of $\overline{{S}^{n-1}} \hookrightarrow \overline{L}$.

Thus by the lemma

\begin{align*}
(D^n, \mathbb{S}^{n-1}) \hookrightarrow (D^n, L)\\
(\overline{D^n}, \overline{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}) \hookrightarrow (\overline{D^n}, \overline{L})
\end{align*}

Induce isomorphisms at the homology level.

Now consider the conmutative diagram of inclusions

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
(D^n,\mathbb{S}^{n-1}) @>e>>  (D^n,L) @<c<<  (\overset{\circ}{D^n}, L- \mathbb{S}^{n-1}) \\
@VgVV @VVdV @VVaV \\
(\overline{D^n}, \overline{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}) @>f>> (\overline{D^n}, \overline{L}) @<b<< (\overline{\overset{\circ}{D^n}}, \overline{L- \mathbb{S}^{n-1}})\\
\end{CD}
$$

$a$ is an homeomorphism since the characteristic map doesn't identify anything in the interor of $D^n$. $c$ and $b$ are excision maps and thus induce isomorphisms. Thus $d$ is an isomorphism. Finally $e$ also induces isomorphisms by the lema. We conclude that the inclusion $f_\circ g $ induces isomorphisms.